# Viewing String given in a log in logcat - Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-logcat

I am a beginner in android.I cant able to view log String which i have given in program.Is there any way to view it. Pleases guide me.
Thank you for your response.

Comment: So you are not able to see it on android monitor in your android studio?

Answer (score 1):

### Logcat

[image: Logcat]

### Code

`Log.i("TEST", "logcat info test");` ====> Log level: **info**

`Log.v("TEST", "logcat verbose test");` ====> Log level: **verbose**

`Log.e("TEST", "logcat error test");` ====> Log level: **error**

```
...
```

Depending on what static method of the `Log` class that you call, switch to the appropriate view perspective as shown above.